# How do I properly import a python module I created?

Tags: python-3.x

Both my main python file and my module python file are in the same directory. When I try and define a new variable by calling a class in my module file VSCode tells me the variable is undefined.

module.py

```py
class Shirt:

    def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):
        self.color = shirt_color
        self.size = shirt_size
        self.style = shirt_style
        self.price = shirt_price

    def change_price(self, new_price):

        self.price = new_price

    def discount(self, discount):

        return self.price * (1 - discount)
```

shirt.py

```py
import os
import shirt_module

new_shirt = Shirt('red', 'S', 'short-sleeved', 15)
```

VSCode is saying that the variable Shirt in the shirt.py file is undefined. Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: you should name the file `shirt_module.py` and import the way you did but use it like `new_shirt = shirt_module.Shirt('red', 'S', 'short-sleeved', 15)`

Comment: Thanks Rog, that worked! I overlooked specifying the module first where the class resides.